# RTK Query and Authentication

Tags: authentication, redux-toolkit

I'm planning on using RTK for a store I'm building but when it comes to authentication through JWTs I'm not sure if I should be using it.

I understand that it caches data upon retrieval but I wouldn't want it to cache the JWT token would I?

Should I use axios as well as JWT?

I've done a bit of research but didn't land on anything yet, I'll be continuing my research and hopefully will find an answer here.